# Is there any lightweight IDE for Java programming using Maven and Hibernate/Spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, netbeans

I am working in a Java web project using Hibernate/Spring MVC technology with Maven. Previously I used IntelliJ IDEA but it was expensive and quite heavy. I switched to Netbeans in hope that it should be free and consumes lesser memory. Well it is indeed free but it consumes as much memory as the commercial tool. Everytime I run my Netbeans 8.2 tool, I can't do anything else other than leaving **just 1** Google Chrome **tab** for testing and 2 command line windows (1 for running maven and 1 for running Tomcat). This is ridiculous.

I have been looking for another software but still can't find anything that can both help me to work on a project using Hibernate/Spring and Maven (like Netbeans) but consumes lesser memory than Netbeans. Does anyone know any tool out there that can do this? Thanks.

Comment: There's eclipse. Personally, I think you'd be better off investing in more memory.

Comment: As for eclipse, I'll give it a try. I hope it will consume lesser memory than Netbeans does. 

But for more RAM, I'm not sure that's possible or not. I'm talking about my work pc. My company has a long and complex procedure about adding more RAM based on priority of each project. Unfortunately my current project doesn't have high priority so I'll have to wait in a very long queue. I'm not the one that made those rules.

Comment: Seriously, get the RAM. My Eclipse is configured with -Xmx4G, but uses only 2 GB, which may cost some $30. Unless you work for under $1 per hour, you can tell the leaders of your company that they're money wasting idiots. Time is money and lack of RAM costs a lot of time. (I've got me 32 GB many years ago).

Comment: Thanks @maaartinus for your suggestion. If it were my home pc or if my project had a high priority, things would be much simpler (my home pc has 16GB of RAM). I know the company's management board is wrong about their rule but as long as I can't find better job, I'll have to put up with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running into memory issues, that is certainly a RAM issue. [This article](https://www.pcworld.com/article/129177/article.html) might be helpful.

Most IDEs are going to consume *a lot* of memory, because they're complex applications that load many different tools into memory. Many low-power systems can hardly handle the [lexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) that is so useful in IDEs.

I suggest you give a text editor a try, such as [Atom](https://atom.io/) or [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/). You can then use plugins and the command line tools for Hibernate/Spring and Maven to manually perform the tasks the IDEs were doing for you. This will have a learning curve, but the command line often provides greater control and power over a GUI. A text editor will certainly use less memory.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll give those tools a try. Another thing about Netbeans is its suggestion feature which automatically provides list of methods and fields of a class when pressing "." and/or ctrl-space on the keyboard. Sometimes it automatically added missing "import" if necessary. Do those tools support that?

Comment: There are vast amounts of plugins for both tools. Search "autocomplete" in their plugin libraries.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give them a try.

Comment: i only need less lag and don't wait 5 minute to load a project.